# Error while open api to ballerina auto source code generation

Tags: wso2, openapi, ballerina

I got an error while I auto generate ballerina source code from open API 3. 
yaml file includes

```
content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              oneOf:
                - $ref: "#/components/schemas/incidentResolved"
                - $ref: "#/components/schemas/incidentUpdate"
                - $ref: "#/components/schemas/postmortem"
```

Using `oneOf` is the reason for the error.

```
error: Error occurred when generating GEN_SERVICE for openapi file at incidentReporting.yaml. null
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I guess it only supports allOf for the moment. https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/7f0a56c3499684ef05cf437f104f2c9c83b43e62/misc/openapi-ballerina/modules/openapi-to-ballerina-generator/src/main/java/org/ballerinalang/openapi/model/BallerinaSchema.java#L194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ballerina OpenAPI tools do not support "oneOf"... it will only work with "allOf" for one content type per operation. At the moment the Ballerina Tooling team is working on adding support for most of the OpenAPI specification and JSON Schema Specification.

Issue reported on this: 
https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/17034